# A general question on $L^1$-space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are two ($\sigma$-finite) measures on a measurable space $(\mathbb{X},\mathcal{X})$ such that $\nu\ll \mu$. Is there any result like if $E$ is closed in $L^1(\mu)$, then $E$ is closed in $L^1(\nu)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  For example, suppose $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$ and 
$d\nu(x)  = \exp(-x) d\mu(x)$.  The indicator functions of intervals $[n,n+1]$ 
form a closed set in $L^1(\mu)$ (because any two have distance $2$), but converge to $0$ in $L^1(\nu)$.

Comment: Thanks @Robert Israel: Can we say any such result if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are finite measures and $\nu\ll\mu\ll\nu$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mu$ be Lebesgue mesure on $[0,1]$ and let $\nu$ be defined by $d\nu(x)=\sqrt{x}d\mu(x)$. Then $1/x \in L^{1}(\nu)$, but $1/x \notin L^{1}(\mu)$. $L^{1}(\mu)$ is not closed in $L^{1}(\nu)$, though $L^{1}(\mu)\subset L^{1}(\nu)$ and $L^{1}(\mu)$ is dense in $L^{1}(\nu)$. You have $\mu \ll \nu \ll \mu$, and both measures are finite.